# Datagridview combobox not updating

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I am using datagridview combobox for problems and sub problems. On selection of problems its sub problem combobox datasource filled according to problem. [image]

For updating sub problem i am using

```
private void dataGridView2_CellValueChanged_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView2.Columns[8].Index && e.RowIndex>-1)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dataGridView2.Columns["KeyProblemDescription"].Index] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
            if (cell == null)
                return;
            Guid primaryProblem = new Guid(dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dataGridView2.Columns["PrimaryKeyProblem"].Index].Value.ToString());
            cell.DataSource = dbCalling.getPrimaryKeyProblemDescription(primaryProblem);
            cell.DisplayMember = "Name";
            cell.ValueMember = "Id";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
 public DataTable getPrimaryKeyProblemDescription(Guid keyProblem)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Id]  ,[KeyProblemDescription] as Name
  FROM [KeyProblemDescription] where [PsfKeyProblemId]=@keyProblem "))
                {
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keyProblem", keyProblem);
                    return selectDataTable(com);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }


public DataTable selectDataTable(SqlCommand com)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        com.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = com;
                        con.Open();
                        sda.Fill(datatable);
                        return datatable;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Its working fine when i first select problem but in case when i am fetching problem and sub problem from database its giving exception datagridview combobox sub problem value is not valid. Reason behind this is sub problem datasource is not filled according to problem. How can i get rid this.

Edit

When i am feeling datasource  cell value change event is fired for row index -1 only, why so ?? not for 1,2,3.....

Comment: what is type of getPrimaryKeyProblemDescription? BindingList<T>? can you show getPrimaryKeyProblemDescription code?

Comment: please check my edit..

Comment: try to add manual refresh: cell.DisplayMember = "Name";
            cell.ValueMember = "Id"; cell.Items.Refresh();

Comment: when i should do manual refresh.

Comment: after cell.ValueMember = "Id"; call cell.Items.Refresh();

Comment: How is your grid view populated? i.e. bound mode (using data source) or something else? could you post a full example with just 2 columns ("PrimaryKeyProblem" and "KeyProblemDescription")

Comment: refer : http://hubpages.com/technology/Cascading-ComboBox-in-C-SharpNet

Answer (score 0):

The code looks mostly ok, except that your second if statement seems incomplete.

try

```
if (cell == null)
{
    return;
}
else 
{
    Guid primaryProblem = new Guid(dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dataGridView2.Columns["PrimaryKeyProblem"].Index].Value.ToString());
    cell.DataSource = dbCalling.getPrimaryKeyProblemDescription(primaryProblem);
    cell.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cell.ValueMember = "Id";
}
```

Given your second `if` is missing some brackets, id expect you are already getting syntax errors

Comment: You don't have to use the brackets if you use just 1 statement.

Comment: And you don't have to use the `else`, since if `cell` is `null` he uses `return`. so the code wouldn't continue anyhow.

Comment: Aha, i see. I was taught to always encapsulate - guess it doesn't hurt, though i understand not needing the else in this case

Answer (score 0):

The exception your getting seems to be:

> DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid

In that case the problem would be that you bind to a new list of values but the selected Id is still one not in that new list. You can clear the current value by setting `cell.Value = null` or directly setting it to an existing new Id.

```
private void dataGridView2_CellValueChanged_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView2.Columns[8].Index && e.RowIndex>-1)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dataGridView2.Columns["KeyProblemDescription"].Index] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
            if (cell == null)
                return;
            Guid primaryProblem = new Guid(dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dataGridView2.Columns["PrimaryKeyProblem"].Index].Value.ToString());
            cell.Value = null; //added code
            cell.DisplayMember = "Name";
            cell.ValueMember = "Id";
            cell.DataSource = dbCalling.getPrimaryKeyProblemDescription(primaryProblem);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instead just generate the individual combobox values when the datarow cell edit event triggers. The following code will generate both the parent and child, but you could just auto gen the child on edit and populate the parent in a different method and not change it every time it is edited.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {

        // Parent Problem Combobox
        if (e.ColumnIndex == x && e.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbx = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[indexofparent];
            if (cbx?.Items != null)
                cbx.Items.Clear();


            // Populate RESULT datatable from a SQL query

            foreach (DataRow item in result.Rows)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item[0].ToString()))
                    cbx.Items.Add(item[0].ToString());
            }
        }
        // Populate child
        else if (e.ColumnIndex == x && e.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbx = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[indexofchild];
            if (cbx?.Items != null)
                cbx.Items.Clear();

            // Populate RESULT datatable from a SQL query

            foreach (DataRow item in result.Rows)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item[0].ToString()))
                    cbx.Items.Add(item[0].ToString());
            }


        }
    }
```